# Render a marker component with React and google-react-map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm doing a simple project with React using google-map-react library, by default there is a marker, on click on the map i want to render marker component showing the marker icon. Here is my code, also when i click on console log it logs the latitude and longitute but the marker icon is not displaying, i like to understand what i'm doing wrong, any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image: google map with marker icon]

here is my marker component code

```
import { FaMapMarkerAlt } from "react-icons/fa";

const Marker = ({ id, lat, lng }) => {
const handleClick = () => {
if (onClick) {
  onClick(id);
}
};
return (
<div
  className="marker"
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    // transform: `translate(-50%, -100%)`,
    left: `${lng}%`,
    top: `${lat}%`,
  }}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  <FaMapMarkerAlt style={{ color: "blue", fontSize: "40px" }} />
</div>
);
};

export default Marker;
```

My map component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import Marker from "./Marker/Marker";

const WorldMap = ({ center, zoom }) => {
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(true);

const onMapClick = ({ lat, lng }) => {
const newMarker = {
  id: Date.now(),
  position: { lat, lng },
  isClicked,
};
setMarkers((prevMarkers) => prevMarkers.concat(newMarker));
console.log("map is clicked", "Markers state:", markers);
};
return (
<div className="map">
  <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY }}
    defaultCenter={center}
    defaultZoom={zoom}
    onClick={onMapClick}
  >
    {/* {markers.map((marker, id) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          key={marker.id}
          lat={marker.position.lat}
          lng={marker.position.lng}
        />
      );
    })} */}
    {isClicked
      ? markers.map((marker) => (
          <Marker
            key={marker.id}
            lat={marker.position.lat}
            lng={marker.position.lng}
          />
        ))
      : null}
    <Marker />
  </GoogleMapReact>
  </div>
 );
};

WorldMap.defaultProps = {
center: {
lat: 54.526,
lng: 15.2551,
},
zoom: 7,
};

export default WorldMap;
```

Comment: Do you really need to add a custom marker? It would be easier for you just to use the built in marker itself.